# Suggestion for getting a type of plot

Tags: python, visualization-software

I am planning to use python to get a plot like this [image].

But, I am only able to get this, [image]

So, I would appreciate it if someone helps me with this issue,
(Maybe how to format the data):  **How to have lower X-axis values highlighted like in the original plot.**

Please check the code below and looking forward to your suggestions.
Numpy and Matplotlib are being used.

```
    x = [192, 188/4, 168/24, 144/48, 96/96]
    ys = [[2.20, 0.758, 0.691], [1.44, 0.708, 0.733], [0.491, 0.379, 0.440], [0.349, 0.350, 0.165], [0.199, 0.157, 0.163]]
    
    print(len(x), len(ys))
    colors = [["r", "y", "g"], ["r", "y", "g"], ["r", "y", "g"], ["r", "y", "g"], ["r", "y", "g"]]
    print(colors)
    
    for y, x, c in zip(ys, x, colors):
    #     print(y, [x])
    #     print([x]*len(y))
        plt.scatter([x]*len(y), y, color = c)    
        
    
    plt.xticks([192, 188/4, 168/24, 144/48, 96/96])
    plt.xlabel("Si/Al Ratio")
    plt.ylabel("Diff Coeff (Ang**2)")
    # plt.legend(['Water_Cubic{}'.format(i) for i in [12, 24, 48]], loc=2, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), borderaxespad=0., fontsize=11)
    plt.title("Si/Al vs Diff Coeff at 300k for Water Content (12, 24, 48)")
```

Comment: I'm maybe not understanding the question. I don't see any highlighted values in the upper plot. Do you just want different values for the xticks? You are setting these manually, so you can either specify a different set of these or let matplotlib set them automatically based on your x values.

Comment: This question is not related to Materials modeling and instead should be asked on e.g. StackOverflow.

Comment: @PeterSchindler it was asked on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72959365/1271772

Comment: This was both asked and answered on SO around the same time as you asked the question here. Please refrain from cross posting questions on multiple SE, as this makes it difficult for users to know where else a question has been asked and leads to duplicated effort when providing answers. At a minimum, you should include a link to any alternate versions of your question on other sites.

Comment: matplotlib can do everything you want, but matplotlib cannot do it and keep you sane.

Comment: Maybe the question is looking for regularly spaced x-axis labels with the infinity sign, something like `plt.gca().set(xticks=np.arange(0,201,50), xticklabels=['0', '50', '100', '150', r'$\inf$'])`

Comment: @B.Kelly What plotting library can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very unclear what you are asking about.
"How to have lower X-axis values highlighted like in the original plot."

There is no x-axis highlighting in any of the plots.

I tried to convert your data into a plot that looks a lot like the one you aimed for, here is my best guess:

[image]

The code used to generate the plot can be found at https://github.com/erikkjellgren/Shared_scripts/blob/main/notebooks/sial_plot.ipynb